# AWS CDK - SecurityGroup creation Typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm trying to migrate the follow CloudFormation resource to CDK using typescript:

```
ALBSecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref VPCId
        GroupDescription: !Sub "${Application}-${Environment}-alb-sg"
        SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: !Ref SecurityGroupIngressCidr
```

I have tried with this (I don't know how to create the necessary properties):

```
const albSecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, "ALBSecurityGroup", {
      vpc: Vpc.fromLookup(this, id, {
        vpcId: props.vpcId.stringValue
      }),
      description: appEnv + "-alb-sg"
    })
```

And using Cfn constructor like this (I don't know how to join CfnSecurityGroup with CfnSecurityGroupIngress):

```
const x = new CfnSecurityGroupIngress(this, id, {
      ipProtocol: "tcp",
      fromPort: 443,
      toPort: 443,
      cidrIp: props.securityGroupIngressCidr
    }); 

    const albSecurityGroupCfn = new CfnSecurityGroup(this, id, {
      vpcId: props.vpcId.stringValue,
      groupDescription: appEnv + "-alb-sg"
    });
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What's the issue? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your answer looks cleaner by using `CfnSecurityGroup`, but just for completeness and to show the approach that can be taken to achieve the same using an higher order construct `SecurityGroup` would be as below:

```
import { SecurityGroup, Peer, Port, Vpc } from '@aws-cdk/aws-ec2';

....

const vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, id, {
  vpcId: props.vpcId.stringValue
});

const albSecurityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, 'MyALBSG', {
  vpc,
  description: appEnv + "-alb-sg",
  allowAllOutbound: true
});

albSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
  Peer.ipv4(props.securityGroupIngressCidr), 
  Port.tcp(443), 
  "Allow HTTPS traffic from CIDR IPs"
);

....
```

I would highly suggest going through the overview section of whichever service module you plan to use in CDK. [Here is the one for `aws-ec2`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-ec2-readme.html#allowing-connections) which shows how `SecurityGroup` can be written.

You might as well use `loadBalancer.connections.allowFrom()` directly instead of explicitly creating a security group for your ALB. Assuming your ALB construct is named as `loadBalancer`, this would look something like:

```
loadBalancer.connections.allowFrom(
  Peer.ipv4(props.securityGroupIngressCidr), 
  Port.tcp(443), 
  'Allow inbound HTTPS from CIDR IPs'
);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your comments. They have helped me a lot. I have been reading the official documentation, but there are some things that are still not clear to me. In fact my previous answer doesn't work, because I get this error:

throw new Error('Trying to resolve() a Construct at ' + pathName);

The documentation mentions that I should use CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty, but I can't find a way to use it.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the documentation you are referring to? Also, you can elaborate on the problem you are facing with `CfnSecurityGroup`? You can add them as comments to your own answer since your answer refers to `CfnSecurityGroup`. If you have more information to share then we have to take it offline. One easy way to showcase the problem is to write a [gist](https://gist.github.com/), you can use proper code formats and describe your problem at the same time. I would suggest to create a gist and provide as much information as you can.

Comment: @dmahapatro thanks a lot for the answer using the `SecurityGroup`.

Comment: can someone help me here related to aws CDK security group 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69732793/aws-cdk-typescript-issue-the-expected-type-comes-from-property-securitygroups

Answer (score 3):

Today I realized that it was an easy solution.

```
const albSecurityGroupCfn = new CfnSecurityGroup(this, id, {
  vpcId: props.vpcId.stringValue,
  groupDescription: appEnv + "-alb-sg",
  securityGroupIngress: [
    new CfnSecurityGroupIngress(this, id, {
      ipProtocol: "tcp",
      fromPort: 443,
      toPort: 443,
      cidrIp: props.securityGroupIngressCidr
    })
  ]
});
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: (dmahapatro)

With the above approach you would receive a compile time error showcasing that you need an appropriate type. Here is a minor tweak to above solution:

```
const albSecurityGroupCfn = new CfnSecurityGroup(this, id, {
  vpcId: props.vpcId.stringValue,
  groupDescription: appEnv + "-alb-sg",
  securityGroupIngress: [{
    ipProtocol: "tcp",
    fromPort: 443,
    toPort: 443,
    cidrIp: props.securityGroupIngressCidr
  }]
});
```

`securityGroupIngress` expects below types:

```
Type: Array<CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty | cdk.IResolvable> | cdk.IResolvable
```

When you provide array of `CfnSecurityGroupIngress` it does not resolve to any of those types. A better way to handle it is using an array of objects which will coerce to `Array<CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty>` by default. The latest answer shows that you do not need to instantiate `CfnSecurityGroupIngress` for `securityGroupIngress`.

On a side note, if VS Code is used as the IDE for CDK, it catches those compile time errors beforehand.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. I am updating your answer here, try that out, you should be good.

Comment: Great! I was trying to solve it, and I didn't know how to do it. In fact the VSCode does not show me the compilation error. Thank you again