# AWS CDK Typescript issue: The expected type comes from property 'securityGroups' which is declared here on type 'InstanceProps'

Tags: typescript, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, amazon-aurora, aws-security-group

What can I do here?

I am getting this error:

```
Type '{ instanceType: ec2.InstanceType; securityGroup: ec2.SecurityGroup; vpc: ec2.IVpc; vpcSubnets: { subnetName: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'InstanceProps'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'securityGroup' does not exist in type 'InstanceProps'. Did you mean to write 'securityGroups'?
```

My code:

```
const dbClusterSecurityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, "dbClusterSg", {
      allowAllOutbound: true,
      description: `Project ${projectName} Service database cluster`,
      securityGroupName: `${projectName}Database`,
      vpc,
    });
    dbClusterSecurityGroup.node.applyAspect(new cdk.Tag("Name", "serviceDatabaseCluster"));
    dbClusterSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
      vpnSG,
      ec2.Port.tcp(postgresDatabasePort),
    );
    dbClusterSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(
      codeBuildProjectSG,
      ec2.Port.tcp(postgresDatabasePort),
    );
if (activeRegion === this.region) {
      const postgresCluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, "dbCluster", {
        backup: {
          preferredWindow: "05:00-06:00",
          retention: cdk.Duration.days(30),
        },
        defaultDatabaseName: postgresDatabaseName,
         engine: [ rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres ],
         engineVersion: [ rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_13_3 ],
        engineVersion: postgresDatabaseEngineVersion,
        instanceProps: {
          instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T3, ec2.InstanceSize.MEDIUM),
          *securityGroup: dbClusterSecurityGroup,*
          vpc,
          vpcSubnets: { subnetName: "data" },
        },
```

when tried securityGroups: dbClusterSecurityGroup,
getting error :

```
Type 'SecurityGroup' is missing the following properties from type 'ISecurityGroup[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
The expected type comes from property 'securityGroups' which is declared here on type 'InstanceProps'
```

Updating my question:

securityGroups: [dbClusterSecurityGroup] this worked but now getting errors

```
 engine: [ rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres ],
 engineVersion: [ rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_13_3 ],
```

Error is:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
lib/database-stack.ts:120:9 - error TS2739: Type '((props: AuroraPostgresClusterEngineProps) => IClusterEngine)[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IClusterEngine': singleUserRotationApplication, multiUserRotationApplication, supportedLogTypes, bindToCluster, engineType

120         engine: [ rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres ],
            ~~~~~~

  node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-rds/lib/cluster.d.ts:26:14
    26     readonly engine: IClusterEngine;
                    ~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'engine' which is declared here on type 'DatabaseClusterProps'
```

Comment: `securityGroups: [dbClusterSecurityGroup]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with checking the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-rds.InstanceProps.html

As you can see, `InstanceProps` doesn't have a `securityGroup` parameter, just `securityGroups`, which accepts an *array* of `ISecurityGroup` objects, not just one `ISecurityGroup`, which you're passing. This is how it should look like:

```
securityGroups: [dbClusterSecurityGroup]
```

Comment: Argument of type '{ backup: { preferredWindow: string; retention: cdk.Duration; }; defaultDatabaseName: string; engineVersion: string; instanceProps: { instanceType: ec2.InstanceType; securityGroups: ec2.SecurityGroup[]; vpc: ec2.IVpc; vpcSubnets: { ...; }; }; ... 6 more ...; storageEncrypted: true; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DatabaseClusterProps'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'engineVersion' does not exist in type 'DatabaseClusterProps'.ts(2345)

Comment: securityGroups: [dbClusterSecurityGroup]
this worked but it gave the above error

Comment: error shows: engineVersion: string[]; so I tried engineVersion: [postgresDatabaseEngineVersion], but still same error 'engineVersion' does not exist in type 'DatabaseClusterProps'

Comment: need help what should these 2 vaules be ? engine: [ rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.auroraPostgres ],
        engineVersion: [ rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_13_3 ],

Comment: Did you check the documentation? Does `DatabaseClusterProps` have an `engineVerision` property?

Comment: yes but docs seems to bit tough to understand as it doesn't have a sample example to understand it easily, as I am lacking knowledge of typescript coding.

Comment: No, `DatabaseClusterProps` does not have an `engineVersion` property.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when importing from different packages.

```
import * as iam from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';
import { Effect } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
```

Fix:

```
import { Effect } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
```